# configuration file of consts to many classes

Tags: objective-c, c

Using objective c , I have 2 classes that are using hardware, and are written in `c +objC` .
The other classes in the project are objective c, and they create instance of those classes.

My question .

Lets say I have `classA.m` and `classB.m` . they both have an integer const that needs to be the same say : `const int numOfSamples=7;`

I am seeking for the best solution to create some configuration file, that will holds all this const variables, that both A and B can see them .
I know some ways,but I wonder whats the RIGHT thing to do .

1. I wonder if I can just create a : `configuration.m` and write them into it .
2. to use a `singleton` file that holds all globals .

Number 1 seems to me the best , but how exactly should I do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For approach 1 to work, you need to define two files:

1. a header file where you declare all of your constants;
2. a .m file where your constants are defined and initialized.

In your example:

```
/* .h file */
extern const int numOfSamples;

/* .m or .c file */
const int numOfSamples = 7;
```

Then, you include the .h header in every other file where you need those constants. Notice the `extern` keyword, this will declare the variable without also defining; in this way, you can include the .h file multiple times without having a duplicate symbol error.

EDIT:

The approach I suggest is the correct way to handle global variables in a C program.

Now, if global variables are a good thing or not, well, that is a longer story.

Generally speaking, global variables are tricky and go against a 40 years long effort towards better encapsulation (aka, information hiding) of data and behavior in a program (see ["On the Criteria to Be Used in Decomposing Systems Into Modules"](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/Design/criteria.pdf), David Parnas, 1972).

To further explain this, one aspect of the problem is exactly what you mention in your comment: the possibility of one module changing the value of a global variable and thus affecting the whole behavior of the program. This is recognizedly bad and leads to uncontrollable side effects (in any non trivially sized program).

In your case, I think things are a bit different, in that you are talking about "configuration" and "const" values. This is an altogether different case than the general one and I think you could safely use a header file of consts to that aim.

That said, you understand that the whole theme of configuration is a huge one, in general. E.g., you could need mechanisms to change your program configuration on the fly; in this case the constant variable header approach would be not correct. Or, your program configuration could depend on the state of some remote system (imagine: you are logged in vs. you are not logged in).

I can't guarantee that using a header file is the best approach for your case, but I hope that the above discussion and the example I gave you can help you figure that out.

Comment: thanks a lot. is this a "good" approach , or "popular" way to do that ? and if they where not consts , so in this approach, all classes that use them could change them -and everyone would see that change ?

Comment: thanks a lot. this is exactly how i have seen that . so to use consts its a good way , because you dont change them,so no conflicts are arise .

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use a `plist` file with all your configuration values.

If you have few configuration values, you can use the `Info.plist` file.